# Mapping a value to an other value and back

Tags: algorithm, security, mapping, obfuscation, anonymity

Imagine a value, say '1234'. I want to map that value to an other value, say 'abcd'. The constrains:

1. The length of the target value is equal to the start value
2. The mapping should be unique. E.g. 1234 should only map to abcd and viseversa
3. The mapping process should be (very) difficult to guess. E.g. multiplying by 2 does count
4. The mapping should be reversible
5. The start value is an integer
6. The target value can be of any type

This should be a basic algorithm, eventually I'll write it in Ruby but that is of no concern here.

I was thinking along the following lines:

```
SECRET = 1234
def to(int)
  SECRET + int * 2
end

def fro(int)
  (int - SECRET)  / 2
end
```

Obviously this violates constrains 1 and 3.

The eventual goal is to anonymize records in my database. I might be over thinking this.

Comment: Short question aside: How will you ensure 1 if you want to ensure 6 at the same time?

Comment: Does it bother you if someone else hacks what algorithm is used? A simple hashing (as you suggest) is easy to break and compromises anonymity of the data. Depending on your need I'd suggest you to take a look at one way hashes.

Comment: Yes it would bother me if someone hacks the algorithm. Quite a bit really. And I know my solution is unacceptable, that's why I asked.

And I don't think 1 and 6 conflict. Point 1 merely places a constrain. Point 6 can be dropped. With type I mean integer, char etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I rather think your objectives are too ambitious: why constraint 6?

Second, what you need is technically a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) from the domain of integers.

Third, your constraint 3 goes against [Kerkhoff's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27_principle). You'd be better off with a well-known algorithm governed by a secret key, where the secret key is hard to derive even if you know the results for a large set of integers.

Fourth, what are you anonymizing against? If you are dealing with personal information, how will you protect against statistical analysis revealing that Xyzzy is actually John Doe, based on the relations to other data? There's some research on countering such attack vectors (google for e.g. '[k-anonymization](http://www.google.com/search?q=k-anonymization)').

Fifth, use existing cryptographic primitives rather than trying to invent your own. Encryption algorithms exist (e.g. AES in [cipher-block-chaining](http://www.globalsecuritymag.com/How-can-I-securely-encrypt-short,20081103,5854) mode) that are well-tested -- AES is well supported by all modern platforms, presumably Ruby as well. However, encryption still doesn't give records anonymity in any strong sense.

Comment: Well thank you! Obviously I know little of this field, you've given enough material for the remainder of the day.

I expected your fifth point being raised but is some not better than nothing? Potentially the records travel over an unencrypted line (can't help it) and the 'opportunity' to steal should be as small as possible.

Comment: Some can be better than nothing, but also worse, if e.g. ROT13-level encryption engenders a false sense of security... Are you afraid the learning treshold of using standard encryption algorithms will be too high? I doubt it, but look at it like this: not only is your solution secure against more attacks, but you've learned something much more useful the next time you need to address security issues. Homegrown solutions are likely to fail on both those counts, alas!

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth you giving a little more detail on what you're trying to acheive. Presumably you're worried about some evil person getting hold of your data, but isn't it equally possible that this evil person will also have access to the code that accessed your database? What's to stop them learning the algorithm by inspecting your code?

If you truely want to anonymize the data then that's generally a one way thing (names are removed, credit card values are removed etc). If you're trying to encrypt the contents of the database then many database engines provide well tested mechanisms to do this. For example:

[Best practices for dealing with encrypted data in MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535175/best-practices-for-dealing-with-encrypted-data-in-mssql)

[database encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281618/database-encryption)

It's always better to use a product's encryption mechanism than roll your own.

Comment: The database and the code are separate systems. Compromising the database doesn't necessarily mean a compromised code base.

I want to safeguard as good as I can the data in insecure transmission to the client without irrevocably losing data. Once I know the connection is secure (HTTP vs HTTPS) I want to be able to sent the original data.

Comment: OK. So is your question around encrypting data over the wire rather than the data sat in the database?